# Create loop for multiple URLs loaded from excel in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have about 500 URLs for the different pages, I need to create a loop to open this urls in sequence and do the same actions in all pages. (i.e openeing the first URL and do some actions then open the second URL and do the same actions.

here is my code:

```
public class LoadPages {

  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
  public static final String Path_TestData = "D://WorkSpace/myproject/src/utility/";
  public static final String File_TestData = "TestData.xlsx";


  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData + Constant.File_TestData,"Sheet1");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
C://Users/Admin/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe); 
  driver = new  ChromeDriver();

 baseUrl = "https://3ddiagnostix.com/newcp/?task=22&subID=";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
 }

  @Test
  public void testUntitledTestCase() throws Exception {
String URL1 = ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 2);
driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(UserName);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentDiv']/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]/input")).click();
    driver.get(baseUrl + URL2);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("scroll(0,50)");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DSO"))).selectByVisibleText("2077: 3DDX Sample");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='2077']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DSO"))).selectByVisibleText("30633: SmileSource");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='30633']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnUpdate")).click();
```

Comment: So what is the question? Where are you stuck? Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and error stack trace (if any)

Comment: I think (to avoid duplicate code), you must provide the layer between tests and this 500 url's. This layer must parse/read this url's and send to action step/class.  Maybe via keyword?
in your driver.get(baseUrl + URL2); just type driver.get(urlPage).

Comment: what is the same actions you are performing across all the URLs?

Comment: Here is the action:
driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(UserName);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentDiv']/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]/input")).click();
          newSelect(driver.findElement(By.id("DSO"))).selectByVisibleText("2077: Sample");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='2077']")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DSO"))).selectByVisibleText("30633");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnUpdate")).click();